# How to get a specific line from a .txt (C++)

Tags: c++, iostream, getline

I would like some help with getting the first line from a txt file called "test.txt", I have discovered the getline function however I am not sure why my code doesn't work or what I need to do. I would like to get the **first** line from the .txt file, but it prints "t" for some reason. Feel free to correct me as you please if I am not handling it correctly. This is the code I am using:

```
string FirstLine;
ifstream File("test.txt");
string line;

if (File)
{
    while (getline(File, line))
    {
        FirstLine = line[0];
    }

    File.close();
}
cout << FirstLine;
```

And this is the .txt file:

this is line 1

this is line 2

this is line 3

Comment: If you only want the first line, then why do you have a loop to continue reading lines? Also, `line[0]` is the first character of the line, so you are not saving any lines at all.

Comment: Ah that makes sense about the first character. How do I select the line of the .txt?

Comment: `FirstLine = line;` will assign the read line into `FirstLine`, but with the while loop, you will keep doing that until the end of file and `FirstLine` will be the last line.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first line:

```
string line;
getline(File, line);
```

Your first line of the file is then stored in `line` as a, you guessed it, string

To get all lines (line by line):

```
while(getline(File, line).good())
    //do something with line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string FirstLine;
ifstream File("test.txt");
string line;

if (File)
{
    getline(File, line);
    FirstLine = line;
    File.close();
}
cout << FirstLine;
```

Is the absolute minimum changes you need to your code to make it do what you want to do.  However, there is A LOT of room for improvement on the above code sample.  For example, why create two strings, `line`, and `FirstLine`, just pass `FirstLine` to the `getline()` function.  I just modified what you provided to highlight where the mistakes where.  Hope this helps...